# The probability that each delegate sits next to at least one delegate from another country

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Nine delegates, three each from three different countries, randomly select chairs at a round table that seats nine people. Let the probability that each delegate sits next to at least one delegate from another country be $\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m+n$.

First I want to tackle the total number of possibilities for the arrangements, but since that seems a more troublesome idea, I'll actually get to it later.

Let's fix chair one, the top chair, and let $A, B ,C$ be the countries so we have people: $AAA, BBB, CCC$ total 9.

Case 1: $A$, Case 2: $B$, Case 3: $C$.

**Consider Case 1 First:**
$(A$_ _)( _ _ *)  (* _ _)

Considering the first bracket space first: We have:

Comment: Please fix your title.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I changed the title. How is it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let $A$ denote the event that the delegates from Alaska choose seats next to each other.

Let $B$ denote the event that the delegates from Belgium choose seats next to each other.

Let $C$ denote the event that the delegates from Canada choose seats next to each other.

Then to be found is actually $$1-P\left(A\cup B\cup C\right)$$

With inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:

$$P\left(A\cup B\cup C\right)=3P\left(A\right)-3P\left(A\cap B\right)+P\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)$$

A tip to find $P\left(A\right)$. If the first delegate of
Alaska has taken his place then there are $\binom{8}{2}$ possibilities
left for the other two from Alaska. In $3$ of these cases event $A$ will occur.

Also note that $P\left(A\cap B\right)=P\left(B\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)$ and $P\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)=P\left(B\cap C\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)$. To find $P(B|A)$ and $P\left(B\cap C\mid A\right)$ think of the situation in wich the $3$ delegates from Alaska have allready taken their seats and sit next to each other. Then $\binom63$ possibilities are left for the $3$ delegates from Belgium and in $4$ of the cases they come to sit next to each other, so that $A\cap B$ occurs. In $2$ of the cases $3$ chairs next to each other are left for the $3$ Canadians, so that $A\cap B\cap C$ occurs.

Comment: (Are you one of these Alaska secessionists?)

Comment: @user84413 Actually it is the first time that I encounter the term secessionist (I am Dutch). So let me put you at ease: no.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and of course I was just joking.  (There really are people in Alaska who want to form their own country, though.)

Comment: The Alaska comment is based on the fact that Alaska is not actually a country, just a state within the United States of America. You may want to use [one of the countries that start with the letter A](https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/all-countries.html), such as Afghanistan. That is not necessary, though. And I'm glad you have the same main love that I do!

Comment: @RoryDaulton Ah.. that makes things clear! I won't change it, just to keep the comments relevant. As you will understand your gladness is of course my gladness too.

Comment: Okay, I am trying to find $P(A)$ as a guest I cannot (+1), so I'll pick this. I am having some issues for sure. So I picked the seat at the top for $A$ it is completely fixed. Then there are two cases. Where we have (imagine a circle and to left and right) $A A $*A* and *A*$AA$. Then I got that $P_1(A) = \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{8}{2}}$ but then since $P(A) = 2P_1(A) \implies P(A) =  2 \cdot \frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{8}{2}} > 1$. Where am I going wrong @drhab? Thanks a lot

Comment: If Alaskian $a$ has taken his place then there are $8$ places left for the other $2$ Alaskians. That gives $\binom82$ possibilities. In $3$ of these possibilities the $3$ Alaskians come to sit next to eachother: $\cdots aAA\cdots$, $\cdots AaA\cdots$ and $\cdots AAa\cdots$. The probability that this occurs is $3\times\binom82^{-1}$. I think you are going wrong by practicizing $\binom63$ as numerator.

Comment: What about the other $6$ letters though? Don't you count that in the numerator @drhab? (+1)

Comment: @drhab. Okay, so we fixed the small $a$ so that we dont need to worry about cyclic shifts?

Comment: The other $6$ letters are not counted in the denominator either. I am just looking at spots for $A$ and $A$. $\binom82$ in total and $3$ special. Yes, if $a$ is fixed then you are done with cycling. You can see $a$ as a point that fixes the circle and its orientation.

Comment: @drhab, Are people distinguishable? Like $A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, ..$?

Comment: You can see them as distinguishable, but that only makes things more complicated. Then you force yourself to distinguish between e.g. $A_1A_2A_3$ and $A_1A_3A_2$. There is no need to. Because I do not distinguish I find $\binom82$ possibilities for the two Alaskians, and not $8\times7$.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer.

Comment: @drhab, but they have to be distinguishable if: $aAA, AaA, AAa$ are different arrangements

Comment: @drhab, as I see it, one of the $A's$ is distinguishable so we can avoid cyclic shifts?

Comment: Just start with placing one $a$. Look at it as the first person that takes a seat and let it be that he is Alaskian. From there stop with distinghuising. In fact $P(A)=\frac3{28}$. This can be derived the way I describe: $3\times\binom82^{-1}$, but also you can reason: there are $\binom93$ possibilities for the $3$ alaskians and $9$ of these let them sit next to eachother. So $P(A)=9\binom93^{-1}=\frac3{28}$. There are more ways leading to Rome.

Answer (score 2):

You finished your question at a strange place, so I'll just give some hints now. Clean up your question if you want more detail.

- There exists someone from country A who is not seated next to someone from another country if and only if the three A delegates are seated in a group, AAA.
- There are nine places for that block of 3 A delegates to sit. The other six places can be arranged in any way, and all those seating arrangements will not be included in your desired probability.
- Use those facts to find how many seating arrangements have someone from country A who is not seated next to someone from another country. That will be the same number as for someone from country B and for someone from country C.
- There is double-counting for all those bad seating arrangements in the last hint. The [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for three sets can be used to remove that double counting.
- To do that you will need to find bad seating arrangements due to country A *and* due to country B, etc. That is the same number for A and C, and for B and C. Then find bad seating arrangements due to all three countries A, B, and C.
- The number of all seating arrangements is the same as the number of permutations of 9 objects where 3 are identical, another 3 are identical, and the last 3 are identical. This is a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients). You can also use a multinomial coefficient to do the calculation in my second bullet point, though a binomial coefficient also works there.

Comment: Just to let you know: your main love coincides with mine.