# Distinguishability in Round Table Combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I have stumbled upon many questions, and one of the weaknesses is the ability to test if the concept is distinguishable or not. For example this:

> Nine delegates, three each from three different countries, randomly select chairs at a round table that seats nine people. Let the probability that each delegate sits next to at least one delegate from another country be $\frac{m}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m+n$.

Take the race: $AAA$ Then are the people distinguishable or not? Is it: $A_1, A_2, A_3$ or not? I ask this because of cyclic shifts. I asked this question [Here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399651/the-probability-that-each-delegate-sits-next-to-at-least-one-delegate-from-anoth). But drhab said they are not, but he uses the concept of $AaA$, or $AAa$ or $aAA$? Is there something with the chair being distinguishable or what is the whole issue exactly?

Comment: When you are finding the *probability*, whether you treat the persons as distinct or not, and the chairs as numbered or not, it won't matter. It is a matter of convenience, eg i would prefer to  take the AAA, eg as identical and chairs as unnumbered to reduce complexity, but always place an A at the "top" of the table.

Comment: In most real cases people are distinguishable and chairs are distinguishable.  Sometimes you can save effort and deal with smaller numbers by treating one or both as indistinguishable, but in other cases this assumption may lead you into error.

Comment: The solution is in this webpage.  They have treated it as indistinguishable.http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2011_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an important question; there's a lot of confusion on this issue that comes up regularly in other questions, and it's good to have answers to it in one place here.

Two different cases should be distinguished: Determining probabilities and counting "ways" (of arranging/combining/doing/... things). As true blue anil has pointed out, when you want to determine probabilities, it doesn't matter what you treat as distinguishable. Treating things as distinguishable just multiplies the numerator and the denominator by the same factor when you divide the number of favourable cases by the total number of cases.

What *does* matter is which events you treat as fundamentally symmetric and hence equiprobable. For instance, if you flip two coins, there are $4$ possible ordered tuples ($(H,H)$, $(H,T)$, $(T,H)$ and $(T,T)$) but only $3$ possible unordered tuples ($(H,H)$, $(H,T)$ and $(T,T)$). This has nothing to do with whether you or anyone else can distinguish the coins. You can make the coins as indistinguishable as you like, you can have a machine flip them and then shuffle the flipped coins before you get to see them – none of this will change the fact that the four ordered tuples are equiprobable and the three unordered tuples are not, and you'll get wrong probabilities if you treat the unordered tuples as equiprobable.

That was all about probability; now to counting "ways". In that case, distinguishability is entirely a matter of definition. The question whether it is "correct" to treat things as distinguishable, when posed in this context, is meaningless. The term "distinguishable" is slightly unfortunate here, as it sounds as if it has something to do with our sensory abilities. A better term might be "distinct". The counting task must specify which "ways" are to be counted, and this must include a definition of which "ways" are to be regarded as distinct.

Perhaps it's worthwhile to add that in quantum theory indistinguishability comes into play for particles in a far more profound way than it ever does for coins. Quantum statistics can be derived by requiring that states are either completely symmetric (for bosons) or completely antisymmetric (for fermions) with respect to exchange of indistinguishable particles, with the result e.g. that there are only three and not four possible combined spin states of two bosons with two spin states each, namely $\uparrow\uparrow$, $\frac12(\uparrow\downarrow+\downarrow\uparrow)$ and $\downarrow\downarrow$, and they are equiprobable, leading to an increased probability for states in which the bosons share the same state. So in a sense bosons really do behave like indistinguishable coins would if their indistinguishability had anything to do with probabilities.

Comment: (+1) A question. If the chairs are numbered then do cyclic shifts (rotations) count as different arrangements?

Comment: @Amad27: That might depend on the formulation of the counting task, but generally speaking I'd say that numbering the chairs is an indication of regarding arrangements that differ only in chair numbers as distinct (since otherwise the numbering would be superfluous) -- so yes, generally I'd expect cyclically shifted arrangements to be regarded as distinct in that case.

Comment: Thanks. What if though, in the problem I was doing with the delegates I did NOT number the chairs. If I considered both, the people and the chairs as indistinguishable, what could I have done then/

Comment: @Amad27: Just leave off the factors of $9$ both in the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: no I meant what is a way of computation if you consider all delegates indistinguishable as well as the chairs?

Comment: @Amad27: Unfortunately I don't understand why my comment doesn't answer that question. Why is that not such a way of computation?